# ¿Cómo hago para crear un scrollbar?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

El problema es que la ventana no me muestra todo lo que esta en el código, he escuchado sobre el scrollbar, pero necesito saber como hacer para que funcione.

Tengo este código:

```
def MostrarentradasCompra():
    Categoria = tkinter.Tk()
    Categoria.geometry("1366x768")
    Categoria.title("Categoría")

    Entrada1 = Label(text="Flautas de papa con con chorizo", font=(10)).place(x= 1, y= 1)
    Entrada1Photo = PhotoImage(file= "flautasdechorizo.png")
    Entrada1Photo1 = Label(Categoria, image = Entrada1Photo).place(x=1, y= 25)
    Entrada1des = Label(text="Descripción: Se ponen a cocer las papas en agua y sal. Cuando están listas se hacen puré.\nSe sofríe cebolla, posteriormente se agrega chorizo.\nSe forman flautas con puré y se rellenan de carne y cebolla.\nLuego se fríen, se sirven y se decora con lechuga y cebolla.\nPrecio unitario: 1100 colones", font=(9)).place(x= 250, y= 50)

    Entrada2 = Label(text="Pico de gallo con nachos", font=(10)).place(x= 1, y=190 )
    Entrada2Photo = PhotoImage(file= "piconachos.png")
    Entrada2Photo2 = Label(Categoria, image = Entrada2Photo).place(x=1, y= 210)
    Entrada2des = Label(text="Descripción: Elaborado al picar tomate sin semillas, cebolla morada, culantro, chile jalapeño,\ndiente ajo picado finamente, limón. Se sirve acompañado de nachos.\nPrecio unitario: 1500 colones", font=(9)).place(x= 250, y= 240)

    Entrada3 = Label(text="Sopa de elote", font=(10)).place(x= 1, y= 375)
    Entrada3Photo = PhotoImage(file= "SopadeElote.png")
    Entrada3Photo3 = Label(Categoria, image = Entrada3Photo).place(x=1, y= 395)
    Entrada3des = Label(text="Descripción: Se elabora a partir de sofreír cebolla, hervir leche. A esta leche se le agrega la\n cebolla, consomé de pollo, y el elote luego se cocina hasta hervir \ny se sazona con sal y pimienta. Se utiliza queso como guarnición.Precio unitario: 1450 colones.", font=(9)).place(x= 250, y= 420)

    Entrada4 = Label(text="Crema de almejas", font=(10)).place(x= 1, y= 540)
    Entrada4Photo = PhotoImage(file= "CremaAlmeja.png")
    Entrada4Photo4 = Label(Categoria, image = Entrada4Photo).place(x=1, y= 560)
    Entrada4des = Label(text="Descripción: Elaborado a partir de derretir mantequilla, agregar cebolla y apio, se sofríe.    \n Se agrega harina, y se mezcla, se vierte caldo de pescado, jugo de  \nalmejas, y se sazona al gusto. Luego se agrega la leche, la crema y las\n almejas, se cocina sin dejar que hierva.\nPrecio unitario: 1800 colones", font=(9)).place(x= 250, y= 590)

    Entrada5 = Label(text="Sopa de lentejas con chorizo", font=(11)).place(x= 1, y=725 )
    Entrada5Photo = PhotoImage(file= "SopaLentaja.png")
    Entrada5Photo5 = Label(Categoria, image = Entrada3Photo).place(x=1, y= 745)
    Entrada5des = Label(text="Descripción: Deliciosa sopa de lentejas calientita, con chorizo y tocino acompañado cilantro en\n caldillo de jitomate con un toque picosito de chile ancho. Servida de\n plátanos machos deshidratados y queso panela.Precio unitario: 1600 colones.", font=(11)).place(x= 250, y= 735)
```

Me muestra solo esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3):

Efectivamente puedes usar una barra de desplazamiento, no obstante no es tan simple como puede parecer porque no todos los widgets las soportan. Entre los widgets que si lo hacen están `ListBox`, `Text`, `Entry` y `Canvas`.

Lo que se suele hacer en estos casos es usar un `Canvas` como contenedor y asociar las barras de desplazamiento al mismo. Una forma medianamente simple en tu caso es usar un `Frame` que contenga todos los widgets de tu interfaz y este frame asignarlo al canvas.

```
import tkinter as tk



def mostrar_entradas_compra():
    categoria = tk.Tk()
    categoria.geometry("1366x768")
    categoria.title("Categoría")

    canvas = tk.Canvas(categoria)
    frame = tk.Frame(canvas)

    vertscroll = tk.Scrollbar(canvas, orient='vertical', command=canvas.yview)
    canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vertscroll.set)

    def on_mouse_scroll(event):
        if event.delta:
            canvas.yview_scroll(-1 * (event.delta / 120), 'units')
        else:
            canvas.yview_scroll(1 if event.num == 5 else -1, 'units')

    categoria.bind('<Configure>', lambda _: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))
    categoria.bind('<MouseWheel>', lambda event: on_mouse_scroll(event))
    categoria.bind('<Button-4>', lambda event: on_mouse_scroll(event))
    categoria.bind('<Button-5>', lambda event: on_mouse_scroll(event))

    canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
    canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=frame, anchor="nw")
    vertscroll.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)


    tk.Label(frame, text="Flautas de papa con con chorizo",
             font=10).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="W")
    entrada_photo_1 = tk.PhotoImage(file="flautasdechorizo.png")
    tk.Label(frame, image=entrada_photo_1).grid(row=1, column=0)
    tk.Label(frame, font=9,
             text=("Descripción: Se ponen a cocer las papas en agua y sal."
                   " Cuando están listas se hacen puré.\nSe sofríe cebolla,"
                   " posteriormente se agrega chorizo.\nSe forman flautas con"
                   " puré y se rellenan de carne y cebolla.\nLuego se fríen,"
                   " se sirven y se decora con lechuga y cebolla.\n"
                   "Precio unitario: 1100 colones")).grid(row=1, column=1)

    tk.Label(frame, text="Pico de gallo con nachos",
             font=10).grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="W")
    entrada_photo_2 = tk.PhotoImage(file="piconachos.png")
    tk.Label(frame, image=entrada_photo_2).grid(row=4, column=0)
    tk.Label(frame, font=9,
             text=("Descripción: Elaborado al picar tomate sin semillas,"
                   " cebolla morada, culantro, chile jalapeño,\ndiente ajo"
                   " picado finamente, limón. Se sirve acompañado de nachos.\n"
                   "Precio unitario: 1500 colones")).grid(row=4, column=1)

    tk.Label(frame, text="Sopa de elote",
             font=10).grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="W")
    entrada_photo_3 = tk.PhotoImage(file="SopadeElote.png")
    tk.Label(frame, image=entrada_photo_3).grid(row=6, column=0)
    tk.Label(frame, font=9,
             text=("Descripción: Se elabora a partir de sofreír cebolla,"
                  " hervir leche. A esta leche se le agrega la\n cebolla,"
                  " consomé de pollo, y el elote luego se cocina hasta hervir\n"
                  "y se sazona con sal y pimienta. Se utiliza queso como"
                  " guarnición.Precio unitario: 1450 colones.")).grid(row=6, column=1)

    tk.Label(frame, text="Crema de almejas",
             font=10).grid(row=7, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="W")
    entrada_photo_4 = tk.PhotoImage(file="CremaAlmeja.png")
    tk.Label(frame, image=entrada_photo_4).grid(row=8, column=0)
    tk.Label(frame, font=9,
             text=("Descripción: Elaborado a partir de derretir mantequilla, "
                   "agregar cebolla y apio, se sofríe.    \n Se agrega harina,"
                   " y se mezcla, se vierte caldo de pescado, jugo de  \n"
                   "almejas, y se sazona al gusto. Luego se agrega la leche,"
                   " la crema y las\n almejas, se cocina sin dejar que hierva.\n"
                   "Precio unitario: 1800 colones")).grid(row=8, column=1)

    tk.Label(frame, text="Sopa de lentejas con chorizo",
             font=11).grid(row=9, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="W")
    entrada_photo_5 = tk.PhotoImage(file="SopaLenteja.png")
    tk.Label(frame, image=entrada_photo_5).grid(row=10, column=0)
    tk.Label(frame, font=11,
             text=("Descripción: Deliciosa sopa de lentejas calientita,"
                   " con chorizo y tocino acompañado cilantro en\n caldillo de"
                   " jitomate con un toque picosito de chile ancho. Servida de\n"
                   " plátanos machos deshidratados y queso panela."
                   "Precio unitario: 1600 colones.")).grid(row=10, column=1)

    categoria.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mostrar_entradas_compra()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
 Se ha añadido además de la barra soporte para hacer scroll con la rueda del ratón.

Unas cuantas observaciones:

- No se como importas tkinter, pero por tu código deduzco que lo importas de varias formas. Deberías importarlo de una sola vez y no usar `from tkinter import *`, es una mala práctica.
- Posicionar mediante `place` es útil en algunos casos, especialmente al crear widgets customizados. No obstante, en este caso creo que `grid` es mucho mejor opción, para empezar tu código se descuadra en cuanto cambie la fuente (lo cual puede pasar al ejecutarlo en otro sistema simplemente) o en cuanto una imagen ocupe más espacio de la cuenta. Por otro lado, es muy engorroso ir midiendo pixeles para colocar cada cosa en su lugar. Si no hay algo que te lo impida te aconsejo usar `grid` como hago en el código anterior.
- No debes hacer `var = tk.Label(...).place(...)`. Si haces esto, `var` va a hacer referencia a a salida del método `place`, que retorna `None`. Esto hace la variable completamente inútil, si no necesitas hacer referencia futura a la instancia simplemente haz:

  ```
  tk.Label(...).place(...)
  ```

  Si necesitas la referencia para el futuro, separa la llamada a `place`/`grid`/`pack` de la instanciación:

  ```
  label = tk.Label(...)
  label.place(...)
  ```
- He acortado las líneas para que el código sea más legible. Hay más formas de trabajar con literales de cadena largos, incluyendo el uso de cadenas multilínea con comillas triples. Aparte de esto hay otras modificaciones para que el código siga en lo posible las convenciones de estilo ([PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)), por ejemplo, los nombres en mayúscula y CamelCase se deben reservar para nombrar clases, para variables y funciones se usa minúscula y `_`.

Comment: Excelente respuesta. Lástima no poder darle más votos :-)

Answer (score 0):

gracias.
Adapte tú respuesta a esta funcionalidad, sólo que no me muestra las demás elementos de la lista.
¿Podrías ayudarme?

Postre1 = ["Flan napolitano","23290.png","Descripción:  Elaborado a partir de leche condensada y evaporada, huevo, azúcar, cane-\nla en polvo, extracto de vainilla, queso crema y media crema. Se quema la azúcar previa-\nmente, luego se agrega a un molde, se mezclan los otros ingredientes y después se incor-\npora la mezcla al molde cuando el azúcar se encuentre frio y duro. Se introduce al horno\n en baño maría, a un periodo de 45 minutos, aproximadamente a 170 grados Celsius.", "Precio unitario: 800 colones"]
Postre2 = ["Fondant de chocolate","Choco.png", "Descripción: Elaborado a partir de Chocolate (70 % cacao), mantequilla, azúcar glass, yemas de huevo, harina. Primero se derrite el chocolate y la mantequilla en baño maría, luego dejamos enfriar, se baten las yemas de huevo y el azúcar glass hasta lograr un color amarillo y se unen las mezclas, agregar harina tamizada y se mezcla a mano. Se coloca en moldes y se mete al horno, se deja cocinar en periodo de 7 a 9 minutos.","Precio unitario: 950 colones"]
listaCategoria = []
listaCategoria+= [Postre1]+[Postre2]
Archivo = open("Historial.txt")
Archivo = listaCategoria
print(Archivo[0])

import tkinter as tk

def mostrar_entradas_compra():
    global Archivo
    categoria = tk.Tk()
    categoria.geometry("1366x768")
    categoria.title("Categoría")

```
canvas = tk.Canvas(categoria)
frame = tk.Frame(canvas)

vertscroll = tk.Scrollbar(canvas, orient='vertical', command=canvas.yview)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vertscroll.set)

def on_mouse_scroll(event):
    if event.delta:
        canvas.yview_scroll(-1 * (event.delta / 120), 'units')
    else:
        canvas.yview_scroll(1 if event.num == 5 else -1, 'units')

categoria.bind('<Configure>', lambda _: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))
categoria.bind('<MouseWheel>', lambda event: on_mouse_scroll(event))
categoria.bind('<Button-4>', lambda event: on_mouse_scroll(event))
categoria.bind('<Button-5>', lambda event: on_mouse_scroll(event))

canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=frame, anchor="nw")
vertscroll.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

while Archivo != "":
    SubCategoria = Archivo[0]
    cont= 0
    while SubCategoria != "":
        tk.Label(frame, text= SubCategoria[0], font = 10).grid(row= cont,column= 0, columnspan= 2, sticky= "w")
        foto1 = tk.PhotoImage(file= SubCategoria[1])
        tk.Label(frame, image= foto1).grid(row= cont, column=0)
        tk.Label(frame, font= 9, text= SubCategoria[2]).grid(row=cont, column= 1)
        tk.Label(frame, font= 9, text= SubCategoria[3]).grid(row=cont, column= 2)
        cont = cont + 1
        Archivo = Archivo[1:]
        categoria.mainloop()
```

if **name**=="**main**":
    mostrar_entradas_compra()